# rails bundle error Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundle

I'm trying to install rails, but have some problem:

`ruby 2.0.0
rvm 1.19.6
gems 2.0.3
bundler 1.2.3`

when I run 'bundle install' or 'gem install json -v "1.7.7"', I have:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9 extconf.rb 
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib64/ruby/include/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /home/Hiken/.bundler/tmp/16909/gems/json-1.7.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/Hiken/.bundler/tmp/16909/gems/json-1.7.7/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.7.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.7'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I use ruby 1.9.3 I have the same errors.
Help me, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem with you. Problem has appeare you cause of you haven't ruby-dev and sqlite-dev libraries on your local mashine. Try to install it"

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer about missing Ruby header files from doing a quick google:

"Many packages are split into 'foo' and 'foo-devel', where 'foo-devel' has the header files. Is there a 'ruby-devel' package you can install?"

Is there a dev tools package you can install and try again with?